# NME Compile HTML 5 Error

Tags: haxe, nme

I've been working on a NME application and when I compile it I receive the following error:

"C:\Program Files\Haxe\haxe/lib\nme/3,5,5/nme/errors/EOFError.hx:25: characters 0-18 : Class not found : browser.errors.EOFError
Build halted with errors (haxelib.exe)."

I check and the corresponding class does not appear to exist. I've tried reinstalling NME, however the problem remains.

I'm using Flash Develop, NME 3.5.5 and Haxe 2.10.

I verified that a hello world program would compile properly in both flash and html 5, before starting this project and it still does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't gotten too far along in your project, I would recommend switching to the latest Haxe 3 and NME (or OpenFL, which is still very new).

I know that's not a specific solution to that issue, but the issue may go away, and it's worth upgrading. There is a Windows binary available:

http://haxe.org/download

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond, I did just that and my program compiled properly. Thanks.